# Redis mirroring with two writable instances

Tags: redis, replication, high-availability

I have two redis instances on two different servers.
I want to implement replication/mirroring with both writable instances.

In case of failover one of them, other instance keep all data and be writable.

Also, the client could connect both servers to access any data.

I tried [Redis cluster tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial) and I implemented clustering in redis with 3 masters and 3 slaves but because of my server resource limits, I am trying to do this using two redis instances.

Comment: Redis the open source does not support active-active replication

Comment: @ItamarHaber so what is the solution?

Comment: There isn't one within the scope of the open source project. Redis Labs (disclosure: my employer) provides a commercial solution for that is built on Redis and CRDTs. Alternatively, I've heard that Netflix's dynomite may be able to do what you're asking for.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redis active-active replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21076234/redis-active-active-replication)